# How to implement noSQL database abstraction?

Tags: node.js, model, couchdb, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I use CouchDB, a document oriented database that store data as JSON documents. I use Javascript on the backend, so I can directly store JS object. Currently I have a direct mapping between the models I store in CouchDB and my domain layer. I think it's not a good thing, because I'm totally dependant on this database.

### Example

I have 2 entities **users** and **projects**.
One user can have multiple projects, these models are represented as separate documents in the database:

**user document**

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "entity": "user"
}
```

**projects documents**
The relation are referenced by a property **user_id**.

```
{
  "_id": "2",
  "entity": "project",
  "user_id": "1",
  "name": "project1"
}

// other project document
{
  "_id": "3",
  "entity": "project",
  "user_id": "1",
  "name": "project2"
}
```

My question is:
**Should I keep this convenient mapping between layers or should I create an abstraction layer that transform the models from the database into domain object ?**

Example of a more convenient user domain object:

```
// _id property is replaced by id
// entity property is removed
// projects relations stand in a projects array
{
  id: "1",
  projects: [
   { id: "2", name: "project1"},
   { id: "2", name: "project1"}
  ]
}
```

Note: I would like to read the book "Domain Driven Design" from Eric Evans. Maybe it could help me to see how to manage such models abstractions.

Comment: If you can't afford the book, you can always read what Martin Fowler has to say about DDD Aggregates:  https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question involve a lot DDD.
What are you struggling for are aggregates. Using a nosql db, a document should contain an aggregate.
Using different documents for entities inside the same aggregate will have the effect that persist an aggregate corresponds to multiple documents being stored, that can fails independently (causing a data corruption).
The DDD aggregate instead is the transactional boundary of your domain, the persist of an aggregate must be an atomic operation.

About the technical stuff, if depends remove them from the domain model is nice is clean etc...etc...
But just if leave them cause more problems then find a way to hide them from the domain. So it depends on the scale of the domain.

For more info this can be helpful: [Why limit commands and events to one aggregate? CQRS + ES + DDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822302/why-limit-commands-and-events-to-one-aggregate-cqrs-es-ddd/32826589#32826589)

Comment: Thx for your answer. I use different documents for entities because for example an other entity could have a relation with a project, so I want to have own document id reference. But you're true the data consistency must be handled in the code. I could also want entities to be stored in differents databases.
So the persist of an aggregate would be an atomic action in my business logic layer, but it would be multiple action in my database gateway layer.

Comment: "would be an atomic action in my business logic layer, but it would be multiple action in my database gateway layer" yes and this is the problem, the main purpose of the aggregate in DDD is that when you save it, you can be sure that the entire aggregate is saved. Having multiple operation can cause inconsistency of the data (storing 3 entites and after the first one the db crash). If you can't avoid it, use aggregates with single entities inside them, but don't trust consistency when you save an aggregate in multiple  documents.

Comment: But does that mean that the aggregate modelisation depends on how the data is stored?

Comment: Not so much the model but how the entities are linked together. The purpose of the aggregate is to manage the concurrency of the data modification. So you are free to model your entities as you want, but when you link them together you are creating the aggregate boundary using the id or the entire data structure (as your two example). When you reference another entity with an id you're making a link *outside* of the boundary of your aggregate.

Comment: The way you store in the db should match this kind of decision at domain layer guaranteeing that the storage of two entities *hard* linked is done with a single operation.

Comment: As last thing "I use different documents for entities because for example an other entity could have a relation with a project, so I want to have own document id reference". What you are using to link them together is the **entity id**, not the **document id**, the difference is that the latter is dependant on the db implementation, but your model shouldn't be dependant on the store technology used. The storage model should adapts to your domain model. So if your entity is inside an aggregate it should be reference with the id of the aggregate and (if needed) the id of the entity inside it.

Comment: Ok I think I start to understand what an aggregate is and is not :) I'll definitely read DDD book

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this question is not that much related to DDD, but I am trying to answer it anyway ;-)

I would definitely translate the database objects into domain objects. The reason for this is pretty simple: If you ever change the underlying data store, your objects will change, and then you will have to update your *domain* code for a *technical* reason.

Apart from that, the database objects do contain way more than what is of interest to the domain. This is another reason to get rid off them: Model your domain objects so that they are clean and do what you expect them from.

Moreover, you want to be able to test your domain objects easily. If they contain all the database stuff, this makes it unnecessarily hard.

To cut a long story short: Don't use database objects in your domain layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I was waiting for :)