# Bulk operation in DDD logic

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am currently exploring DDD and have read quite a bit about the topic, but as I am working on more complex scenarios, I am thinking about the proper way to solve the conceptual issue of bulk operations.

I am also using CQRS (which shouldn't contain nested command) approach to solve my problem (and MediatR from the technical perspective).

#### Current State

Imagine I have the following ShoppingController which has 3 endpoints (CreateShoppingList, AddItemToShoppingList, UpdateItemOnShoppingList) each just creating a command that is processed in  command handlers.

**ShoppingController.cs**

```
...
public class ShoppingController {
    ....
    
    [HttpPost]
    Task CreateShoppingList() {
        ...
        _mediatR.Send(new CreateShoppingListCommand(...))
    }

    [HttpPost]
    Task AddItemToShoppingList() {
        ...
        _mediatR.Send(new AddItemToShoppingListCommand(...))
    }

    [HttpPut]
    Task UpdateItemOnShoppingList() {
       ...
        _mediatR.Send(new UpdateItemOnShoppingListCommand(...))
    }
}
```

**ShoppingListCommandHandler** handles CQRS command: It uses some business logic (get from repository, call stuff on Aggregates) and lastly saves the changes.

**ShoppingListCommandHandler.cs**

```
...
public class ShoppingListCommandHandler : 
ICommandHandler<CreateShoppingListCommand>,
ICommandHandler<AddItemToShoppingListCommand>,
ICommandHandler<UpdateItemOnShoppingListCommand> {
    ....
    
    Task Handle(CreateShoppingListCommand command) {
        // Business Logic A
        _shoppingListRepository.SaveChanges();      
    }

    Task Handle(AddItemToShoppingListCommand command) {
        // Business Logic B including _shoppingListRepository.Get() to retrieve the list        _shoppingListRepository.SaveChanges();      
    }

    Task Handle(UpdateItemOnShoppingListCommand command) {
        // Business Logic C including _shoppingListRepository.Get() to retrieve the list
        _shoppingListRepository.SaveChanges();      
    }
}
```

#### The issue

These operations are absolutely fine when being used as atomic units. But I know want to create a process that imports these things from a file.
The process looks as follows:
**Check if the user has a shopping list. If he does, add the items to the list, if they are not there; or update the quantity if it is already there. If he doesn't create the list, and then proceed above.**

Obviously, it would be nice to have some form of validation, whether the user even exists as well (as I could have made a mistake in my file).

So I approached it as follows:

1. Read the file and prepare the command with the only field being the rows I obtained
2. Deploy and process the command

The command handler for this would look as follow:

```
...
public class ShoppingListCommandHandler : 
ICommandHandler<CreateShoppingListCommand>,
ICommandHandler<AddItemToShoppingListCommand>,
ICommandHandler<UpdateItemOnShoppingListCommand>,
ICommandHandler<ImportShoppingListCommand>
 {
    ....
    
    Task Handle(CreateShoppingListCommand command) {
        // Business Logic A
        _shoppingListRepository.SaveChanges();      
    }

    Task Handle(AddItemToShoppingListCommand command) {
        // Business Logic B including _shoppingListRepository.Get()
        _shoppingListRepository.SaveChanges();      
    }

    Task Handle(UpdateItemOnShoppingListCommand command) {
        // Business Logic C including _shoppingListRepository.Get()
        _shoppingListRepository.SaveChanges();      
    }

    Task Handle(ImportShoppingListCommand command) {

        //Validate File
        ...
        // Retrieve all the required things that will be needed in subsequent processing to avoid
making additional DB calls
        ...
        // Custom Business Logic D1 to update existing lists and add/update items
        // Custom Business Logic D2 to create new lists and add/update items
        ....
        _shoppingListRepository.Update(D1);
        _shoppingListRepository.Add(D2);      
    }

}
```

As you can see, the logic for the import is custom written and optimized for the performance. However, my file can possibly contain duplicates (which don't make the file invalid by default, but for instance two rows for the same shopping list) and in the future, the Business Logic A, B and C can contain more validations (such as call shoppingListRepository to check that there is only one shopping list per household).

Is there any way to make this call efficient (not X calls to DB per operation or creating 10 commands for each row to be stored), and make sure that the logic is not fully duplicated, and that I only have to update one thing?

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Well, it is more question about the correct way of doing things in such DDD scenario, but the question also comes down to the fact that in reality, it is actually not fully working due to the fact that I am currently in-the-middle of implementing the scenario with single list per household, and it makes it a little complicated to maintain the same requirements. But thanks for advice and I will also ask for help there as well.

Comment: From the command perspective the import command is what you need (it represents the operation).
Why don't you put the common logic in separate private methods taking parameters common to both use cases?

Comment: @rascio The reason for this is that the Business Logic   A (for instance) requires a call to DB, and although maybe I could pass it to the private method as parameter, I don't think it would obey DDD anymore, unless I am mistaken

Comment: You can do all the queries you want when handling commands, the only real important thing for you about DDD is that the DB operation to write/store your aggregate behind your command should be atomic.
If you are using a relational DB a transaction is ok, if you are using some NoSQL whatever things guarantees you an atomic operation is ok.
More info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822302/why-limit-commands-and-events-to-one-aggregate-cqrs-es-ddd/32826589#32826589).